# VSCode: "Go to definition" from JS url (view url) to the Django view

Tags: javascript, python, django, visual-studio-code

I am using sublime now and want to switch to the vscode but one functionality of sublime holding me so far.

In the posted image below left side is test.js and right side is view.py having simple test_view definition.

If I use go to definition on the **"test_view"** (*at line url: "/test_app/test_view/"+$routeParams.id*) in the JS, sublime redirects to the test_view definition of the Django view.

I am looking similar functionality/configuration in the VSCode.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is such support for it in VSCode.

Comment: yes seems to be

Comment: Have you tried with (ctrl + click) option on test_view string ?

Comment: Are you using any of the Django specific extensions? Do you recommend any?

Answer (score -1):

You can jump to the definition with Ctrl+Click or open the definition to the side with Ctrl+Alt+Click

Comment: I am not asking about go to definition function within JS or JS imported files. Question is navigating to the Django view from JS url.